# Remove drive from soft RAID

Tags: raid, raid1

I have a dedicated server with 3 SSD drives in RAID 1. Output of `cat /proc/mdstat`:

```
    Personalities : [raid1] [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10] 
md4 : active raid1 sdc4[2] sdb4[1] sda4[0]
      106738624 blocks [3/3] [UUU]
      bitmap: 0/1 pages [0KB], 65536KB chunk

md2 : active raid1 sdc2[2] sda2[0] sdb2[1]
      5497792 blocks [3/3] [UUU]
      
md1 : active raid1 sda1[0] sdc1[2] sdb1[1]
      259008 blocks [3/3] [UUU]
      
unused devices: <none>
```

¿How can a drive be safely removed from the soft raid **without loosing** any data?
I would like to remove a drive from the array in order to reformat it and use it independently, while keeping the most important data mirrored.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You've got a three-way mirror there: each drive has a complete copy of all data.  Assuming the drive you want to remove is `/dev/sdc`, and you want to remove it from all three arrays, you'd perform the following steps for `/dev/sdc1`, `/dev/sdc2`, and `/dev/sdc4`.

Step 1: Remove the drive from the array.  You can't remove an active device from an array, so you need to mark it as failed first.

```
mdadm /dev/md1 --fail /dev/sdc1
mdadm /dev/md1 --remove /dev/sdc1
```

Step 2: Erase the RAID metadata so the kernel won't try to re-add it:

```
wipefs -a /dev/sdc1
```

Step 3: Shrink the array so it's only a two-way mirror, not a three-way mirror with a missing drive:

```
mdadm --grow /dev/md1 --raid-devices=2
```

You may need to remove the write-intent bitmap from `/dev/md4` before shrinking it (the manual isn't clear on this), in which case you'd do so just before step 3 with `mdadm --grow /dev/md4 --bitmap=none`, then put it back afterwards with `mdadm --grow /dev/md4 --bitmap=internal`.

Comment: Does this preserve the data on the disk which you remove? I.e. can you afterwards access the data which was on the RAID from the separate disk too?

Comment: @Nobody, if you want to read the data off the removed drive, you should skip step 2.  Virtually all the data is still there after running `wipefs` (it only erases a few key bytes required for filesystem recognition), but reading it becomes an exercise in data recovery rather than just a matter of plugging the drive in.

Comment: Note that `[n/n]` only implies n copies for RAID1. For RAID10, it just means that all `n` disks are present. The number of copies is printed nearby in the `/proc/mdstat` output.

Answer (score 0):

man mdadm:

> ```
>    -r, --remove
>           remove listed devices.  They must  not  be  active.   i.e.  they
>           should be failed or spare devices.
>
>           As well as the name of a device file (e.g.  /dev/sda1) the words
>           failed, detached and names like set-A can be given to  --remove.
>           The  first  causes  all failed device to be removed.  The second
>           causes any device which is no longer  connected  to  the  system
>           (i.e  an  'open'  returns  ENXIO) to be removed.  The third will
>           remove a set as describe below under --fail.
> ```